# Can I use 2 nexuses on one subsidiary

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite you can add multiple nexuses on one subsidiary.

However I am struggling to get the tax codes of the 2nd nexus exposed on transactions. They do not show.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add multiple nexuses on one subsidiary

Once you setup the required nexuses and tax codes and tax schedules

navigate to subsidiary record and under Nexuses add the nexuses you want to be in that subsidiary

Purchase transactions, tax codes are populating based on the shipping address country and tax schedule selected on the item